# Transform a dataframe to use first column values as column names

Tags: r, dataframe, melt

I have a dataframe with 2 columns:

```
  .id vals
1   A   10
2   B   20
3   C   30
4   A  100
5   B  200
6   C  300

dput(tst_df)
structure(list(.id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), vals = c(10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 
300)), .Names = c(".id", "vals"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now i want to have the `.id` column to become my column names and the vals will become 2 rows.

Like this:

```
A    B    C
10   20   30
100  200  300
```

Basically .id is my grouping variable and i want to have all values belonging to 1 group as a row. I expected something simple like melt and transform. But after many tries i still not succeeded. Is anyone familiar with a function that will accomplish this?

Comment: Try to use `tidyr`. The functions are called `spread` and `gather`. In future, `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` will be supported and more powerful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in base R with `unstack`:

```
unstack(df, form=vals~.id)
    A   B   C
1  10  20  30
2 100 200 300
```

The first argument is the name of the data.frame and the second is a formula which determines the unstacked structure.

Comment: @Imo For this example it works indeed, if i do it on my big df it creates a list. Any idea how that can happen?

Comment: This means that you don't have the same number of observations per level (.id). You could detect, create, and `rbind` the missing rows prior to implementing `unstack` if the data.frame structure is important.

Comment: @Imo Thanks for the hints! it seems to work after i removed the missing observations

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `tapply`,

```
do.call(cbind, tapply(df$vals, df$.id, I))
#       A   B   C
#[1,]  10  20  30
#[2,] 100 200 300
```

or wrap it in data frame, i.e.

```
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, tapply(df$vals, df$.id, I)))
```